# Why am I getting the wrong numbers when putting them in a loop?

Tags: c++, function

I am a beginner programmer specially with functions, my "sum" variable keeps returning ridiculous numbers like 32864 when the numbers that were entered were no more than 100, I tried deleting the if statement in the getgrade function but it doesnt seem to help, help me please.
my code goes like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void displayIntro();
int getGrade();
int finalAverage(int, int);

int main()
{
  int grade, sum, numbOfTests, average;
  
  displayIntro();
  
  for (grade; grade != -1; numbOfTests++)
  {
    grade = getGrade();
    sum = sum + grade;
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
  }
  
  average = finalAverage(sum, numbOfTests);
  
  std::cout << "Exam average, including extra credit, "
            << "is: " << average << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}

void displayIntro()
{
  std::cout << "This program will calculate the average(%) of "
            << "exam grades." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "It will also add extra credit points to the exam "
            << "average given the course difficulty." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Enter all of the grades for one student. Type (-1) "
            << "when finished with that student." << std::endl;
  std::cout << "If you have additional students, you will be prompted"
            << " to repeat the program at the end." << std::endl;
}

int getGrade()
{
  int userGrade = 0;
  
  std::cout << "Enter an exam grade (type -1 to quit):" << std::endl;
  std::cin  >> userGrade;
  
  if (userGrade == -1)
    exit;
  
  return userGrade;
}

int finalAverage(int runningSum, int counter)
{
  int final;
  
  final = (runningSum / counter) + 3;
  
  return final;
}
```

Comment: adding warning to build flags `-Wall -Werror` finds many errors in your code: https://godbolt.org/z/9nM53bfxz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the value of `sum`, `grade`, and `numbOfTests` without initializing them. Add initialization like this:

```
int main()
{
  int grade, sum, numbOfTests, average;
  
  displayIntro();

  sum = 0; // initialization of sum
  numbOfTests = 0; // initialization of numOfTests
  
  // initialization of grade
  for (grade = 0; grade != -1; numbOfTests++)
  {
```

Instead of this, you can include initialization in the declaration of variables:

```
int main()
{
  // add "=" plus value for used in initialization to initialize variables
  int grade = 0, sum = 0, numbOfTests = 0, average;
  
  displayIntro();
```

Comment: @EHooligan -- *thinking this was an issue on the compiler's end* -- If a commercial grade compiler couldn't generate proper code from such a toy program, the compiler manufacturer would be laughed out of the business.